# Calculate total hours from returned results

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli

1. Users times are written to DB using:  `$time = date('g:i:s a', time());`

2.) The table looks like:
[image]
3.) The results are narrowed to the current work week using:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
if (date("w")==1){$bow=strtotime("now");} else {$bow=strtotime("previous Monday");}
if (date("w")==0){$eow=strtotime("now");} else {$eow=strtotime("next Sunday");}
$bow=date("m/d/Y",$bow);$eow=date("m/d/Y",$eow);
$ihold=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM timeclock where idex='$data[idex]' AND date  >='$bow' AND date <='$eow' ORDER BY date");
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($ihold)) {WHAT WOULD GO HERE TO PERFORM THE CALC?}
```

**Now here is where Im getting myself lost, I need to calculate the total number of hours worked in the given week based on the times returned in the mysqli query. Since the "time" column represents both starting and ending times i cant really use a method like this below (Or I don't know how to setup the `while loop` to make it work with this)**

```
$start_time = '9:36';
$end_time = '12:36';
$start = explode(':', $start_time);
$end = explode(':', $end_time);
$total_hours = $end[0] - $start[0] - ($end[1] < $start[1]);
echo $total_hours . ' hours';
```

I have seen several examples on STO but they seem to all have/use a single fixed start date+time and fixed end date+time.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your table look like (it's missing yet)..

Comment: Your database is called mysql, not mysqli

Comment: @Pieter Not sure how to answer you, the table image shows up in the post for me.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. It seems to be blocked.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I wasn't referring to the Database, I was refering to `mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM timeclock where idex='$data[idex]' AND date  >='$bow' AND date <='$eow' ORDER BY date");` which is a mysqli_query

Comment: @Pieter (8) columns (idex,employee,date,time,status,daily_hours,weekly_hours,pto_time_acc)   VALUES (2,Jane Doe,07/16/2013,9:10:59 am,stlunch,0,0,0)

Comment: What's what you are doing wrong. You should have referred to database instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use [timediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) with the [hour](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) function:

```
select timediff(hour(date1, date2)) from tbl;
```

Good luck.

Comment: Im not sure how I would implement your suggestion based on the structure of the table above. I think I would have to change the way i am timestamping each record in the DB to make your way work.... can you give and example using the structure above in my table?